# node-gyp rebuild fail , zmq/build file can't create

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-gyp

I use npm install node-gyp and it run well , but when I use npm to install zmq, the node-gyp rebuild fail and the error below. I need the /zmq/build for my program to run.

I try reinstall the node-gyp but didn't work. Is anyone met this situation before?

> zmq@2.15.3 install /lib/jinteki/netrunner/node_modules/zmq

```
node-gyp rebuild

make: Entering directory `/lib/jinteki/netrunner/node_modules/zmq/build'

CXX(target) Release/obj.target/zmq/binding.o../binding.cc:28:17: fatal 

error: zmq.h: No such file or directory

#include <zmq.h>
             ^

compilation terminated.

make: *** [Release/obj.target/zmq/binding.o] Error 1

make: Leaving directory `/lib/jinteki/netrunner/node_modules/zmq/build'

gyp ERR! build error 

gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2

gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules
/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:276:23)

gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)

gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)

gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit 
(internal/child_process.js:204:12)

gyp ERR! System Linux 3.13.0-86-generic

gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules
/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"

gyp ERR! cwd /lib/jinteki/netrunner/node_modules/zmq

gyp ERR! node -v v6.2.2

gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.3.1

gyp ERR! not ok
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have the appropriate zeromq library headers installed. The name of the package that provides these headers varies depending on your platform/distro. See the [`zmq` readme](https://github.com/JustinTulloss/zeromq.node#installing-on-unixposix-and-osx) for complete installation instructions.